# Seems due to syntax-highligfhting tags <sub> </sub> not working any more on the main site

Tags: bug

I just noticed that **[on the main-site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)**, [TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), the look of things shown while editing/typing to the editor-window differs from the look of things after submitting the question/answer.

An example of this behavior is my [answer to the question How do use {} in \tl_set_rescan:Nnn to replace \scantokens?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496965/how-do-use-setup-in-tl-set-rescannnn-to-replace-scantokens/577183#577183):

At the bottom, where I typed the following:

```
<pre><code>\verb<sub>control&nbsp;word&nbsp;token</sub>+<sub>12</sub>t<sub>11</sub>e<sub>11</sub>x<sub>11</sub>t<sub>11</sub>+<sub>12</sub></code></pre>
```

while editing/typing, things looked like this:

[image]

After submitting/cancelling the edit, things look like this:

[image]

**This behavior is new and it distorts answers of mine given in the past.**

Why does the look of things change after submitting?

---

This is for testing-purposes:

```
<pre><code>\verb<sub>control&nbsp;word&nbsp;token</sub>+<sub>12</sub>t<sub>11</sub>e<sub>11</sub>x<sub>11</sub>t<sub>11</sub>+<sub>12</sub></code></pre>
```

yields:

```
\verbcontrol word token+12t11e11x11t11+12
```

Seems the behavior occurs at TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange (the main site)
but does not occur here at TeX-LaTeX-Meta.

Syntax-highlighting at the main site has something to do with it:

At TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange you have syntax-highlighting and things are colored in blue.

At TeX-LaTeX-Meta you don't have syntax-highlighting and things are black.

If on the main site you prepend `<!-- language: lang-none -->`, i.e.,

```
<!-- language: lang-none --><pre><code>\verb<sub>control&nbsp;word&nbsp;token</sub>+<sub>12</sub>t<sub>11</sub>e<sub>11</sub>x<sub>11</sub>t<sub>11</sub>+<sub>12</sub></code></pre>
```

, then on the main site `<sub>..</sub>` are not ignored and things are not colored in blue.

**In the past on the main-site you didn't need to prepend `<!-- language: lang-none -->` and in the past things while editing looked the same as after submitting.**

Did the the way in which syntax-highlighting at the main site works change recently?

Comment: looks fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUd2T.png

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I edited my question and provided an example which nowadays doesn't look fine any more for me both with Chromium and with Thinderbird and with Iceweasel.

Comment: I see. With the new example, I can reproduce this on stackoverflow.com

Comment: The last major change to the syntax highlighting I'm aware of was https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark , but this was already before your answer

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Perhaps this is due to a minor change. In any case I will do everything I can for generally preventing sytrax-highlighting in the future. In my opinion TeX-LaTeX-StackExchange offers too many possibilities through which third parties can interfere and distort a given answer -- either by unqualified editing, or by weird changes to the mechanisms for rendering/displaying. I miss the time when the main place for discussing (La)TeX was usenet / comp.text.tex.

Comment: syntax highlighting is usually quite stable if one uses either indenting or code fences

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Often I face the situation that I can't use code fences or indenting because I need `<sub>..</sub>` or even s.th. like `<kbd>A<sub>12</sub></kbd>` for displaying tokens with category-code (which actually are not code but exist while (La)TeX processes the code). The point is: Between writing my answer and today the way things are displayed changed in a way where the need arises to check all questions/answers ever written by me for proper displaying. **The biggest misconception is that things are presented differently while typing than after submitting.**